# Keep track of objects using a UUID for immediate user feedback during network requests

Tags: android, duplicates, retrofit, uuid

I have a particular situation. I want the user to get immediate feedback on a certain request (I am using `Retrofit` to do requests.

The user makes a `POST` request by an action in the app. Upon success of the request it adds a new object to a `RecyclerView`. The problem is that the request might take longer than 1 second, and I want the user to get immediate feedback ASAP.

Each object has text from a user, and a url associated with that text

What I am thinking is that I have the following code here:

```
public void doRequest(String text, String url) {

    MyObject myObject = null;
    int uuidForObject = generateUUIDForObject(text, url);
    Retrofit.doRequest(new Callback<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MyObject object, Response response) {
            object.setUUID(uuidForObject);
            // Add to adapter and check if there is an object in the list 
            // with a matching UUID, if so then update it
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
    myObject.setUUID(uuidForObject);

    // Add object to the list
}
```

What are thoughts on this? Is this a good way, is there a better way? The premise is to implement immediate feedback for a user.

How would I go about generating a UUID from two strings?

Comment: I'd say it should work, and instant user feedback is always nice. I'd probably just use `UUID.randomUUID()` to generate new ones though.

Comment: Can you post an example below as an answer? Complete with adding / removing objects from `RecyclerView` by using the `UUID`?